# Nested while loops in mysql data retrieval

Tags: php, mysql

I am using nested while loops in order to retrieve information from 2 different tables (students, grades where both of those tables are linked by primary key - "id")

I want it to output in the following format :

```
Student ID "123"

 - Grade 1 for ID "123"
 - Grade 2 for ID "123"

Student ID "555"

 - Grade 1 for ID "555"
 - Grade 2 for ID "555"

Student ID "666"

 - Grade 1 for ID "666"
 - Grade 2 for ID "666"
```

Currently it outputs like this:

```
Student ID "123"

 - Grade 1 for ID "123" 
 - Grade 2 for ID "123"
 - Grade 1 for ID "555"
 - Grade 2 for ID "555" 
 - Grade 1 for ID "666" 
 - Grade 2 for ID "666"

Student ID "555"
Student ID "666"
```

This is the PHP code

```
<?php
include ("../../php/account.php");

$dbh = mysql_connect ( $hostname, $username, $password )
                   or die ( "Unable to connect to MySQL database" );
mysql_select_db( $project );

$s = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM newstudent");
$r = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM grades");  

while($rows=mysql_fetch_array($s))
    {
    echo "Student ID: ".$rows['id']."<br/>";
    echo "First Name: ".$rows['firstname']."<br/>";
    echo "Last Name: ".$rows['lastname']."<br/>";
    echo "Email: ".$rows['email']."<br/>";
    echo "<br/>";

            while($rows=mysql_fetch_array($r))
            {
                echo "Subject: ".$rows['subject']."<br/>";
                echo "Grade One: ".$rows['gradeone']."<br/>";
                echo "Grade Two: ".$rows['gradetwo']."<br/>";
                echo "Grade Three: ".$rows['gradethree']."<br/>";
                echo "<br/>";                
            }

    }

?>
```

If anyone knows a solution please help me out! many thanks!

Comment: Please **do not** use the old and deprecated `mysql_` functions. Use `mysqli_` or `PDO` instead.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Don't use nested loops, use a `JOIN` to get all the results in one query:

```
$q = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM newstudent s
                  JOIN grades g ON s.id = g.student_id
                  ORDER BY s.id") or die (mysql_error());

$last_student = null;
while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($q)) {
    if ($row['id'] !== $last_student) {
        $last_student = $row['id'];
        echo "Student ID: ".$row['id']."<br/>";
        echo "First Name: ".$row['firstname']."<br/>";
        echo "Last Name: ".$row['lastname']."<br/>";
        echo "Email: ".$row['email']."<br/>";
        echo "<br/>";
    }
    echo "Subject: ".$row['subject']."<br/>";
    echo "Grade One: ".$row['gradeone']."<br/>";
    echo "Grade Two: ".$row['gradetwo']."<br/>";
    echo "Grade Three: ".$row['gradethree']."<br/>";
    echo "<br/>";                
}
```

Comment: this should be accepted as it gives the best solution without the need for a loop.

Comment: Edited the SQL to use `ORDER BY` to ensure that all the grades for a student are together in the results.

Comment: @Barmar Everything works perfectly except the student information does not retrieve (the first echo elements)

Comment: Cut-and-paste problem. I used the variable `$row`, but I pasted your code that uses `$rows`. Fixed it.

Comment: Didn't you get notices about use of an undefined variable because of that? Make sure you have error reporting enabled.

Answer (score 2):

Put your grades query inside your students loop and assign the student ID to it, also don't reassign the `$rows` variable inside your loops.

```
$s = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM newstudent");


while($rows=mysql_fetch_array($s))
    {
    echo "Student ID: ".$rows['id']."<br/>";
    echo "First Name: ".$rows['firstname']."<br/>";
    echo "Last Name: ".$rows['lastname']."<br/>";
    echo "Email: ".$rows['email']."<br/>";
    echo "<br/>";

    $r = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM grades WHERE studentID = '" . $row['id'] . "'");  

            while($r=mysql_fetch_array($r))
            {
                echo "Subject: ".$r['subject']."<br/>";
                echo "Grade One: ".$r['gradeone']."<br/>";
                echo "Grade Two: ".$r['gradetwo']."<br/>";
                echo "Grade Three: ".$r['gradethree']."<br/>";
                echo "<br/>";                
            }

    }
```

Comment: Also - stop using `mysql` functions, they are deprecated. Use `mysqli` instead or `PDO` functions - see the manual.

Answer (score 2):

You are overriding the `$rows` variable.

Comment: True, but it has nothing to do with the problem. He's not depending on the variable's old value after he overwrites it.

Answer (score 1):

you are overwriting the $rows variable in the second loop, i think.
try using 2 different variables

edit:
The inner loop simply states "print all the grades" , so it has no relation with the student you are examining in the outer loop.

There is surely the needing of a foreign key that allows you to take the grades of only the student you are taking from the first loop, as someone else noticed.

Comment: Tried using different variable, exactly the same output

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
<?php
include ("../../php/account.php");

$dbh = mysql_connect ( $hostname, $username, $password )
                   or die ( "Unable to connect to MySQL database" );
mysql_select_db( $project );

$s = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM newstudent");

while($rows=mysql_fetch_array($s))
    {
    echo "Student ID: ".$rows['id']."<br/>";
    echo "First Name: ".$rows['firstname']."<br/>";
    echo "Last Name: ".$rows['lastname']."<br/>";
    echo "Email: ".$rows['email']."<br/>";
    echo "<br/>";

$r = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM grades");  

            while($rows1=mysql_fetch_array($r))
            {
                echo "Subject: ".$rows1['subject']."<br/>";
                echo "Grade One: ".$rows1['gradeone']."<br/>";
                echo "Grade Two: ".$rows1['gradetwo']."<br/>";
                echo "Grade Three: ".$rows1['gradethree']."<br/>";
                echo "<br/>";                
            }

    }

?>
```

Here You are overriding the `$rows` variable.So try to use different variable names.